# Symfony call a reusable bundle like a service

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to create a reusable bundle to manage basket in webstore application...

I create every desired action in a reusable bundle using a controller like addBasketAction, removeBasketAction and so on... The classical

Everythings works fine, but now I'm litteraly stuck about how to "call" my bundle from my "principal" application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont call a bundle but you have to register your bundle in the AppKernel.php file:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [

            // ...

            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new Company\CustomBundle\CompanyCustomBundle(),
        ];
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you will need to import your routes too but i dont know if you use annotations for your routes or a yaml file.

## read more:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html

**[edit]**

Reading your topic title it looks like that you are confusing bundles and services. You can add a service in your bundle on the same way as you can add this service in your AppBundle:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container